# Vue listen and handle from Emits from elements inside slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Basically I have Parent, child, child-of-child component while child component have 2 named slots and child-of-child component have 1 slot so template ends up like this:

Structure of the components

```
<parent>
    <child>
       <child-of-child></child-of-child>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Parent tempalte:

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <labeled-menu>
                <label slot="label">
                    Open Menu
                </label>
                <ul slot="menu">
                    <li v-for="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" @click="$emit('test', `${i} li is clicked`)">List {{i}}</li>
                </ul>
            </labeled-menu>
        </div>
     </template>
```

Child Template with 2 named slots while the 'menu' slot is passed as slot of the child-of-child component:

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <div @click="show">
                <slot name="label">

                </slot>
            </div>
            <v-dialog :class="getMenuSize" :is-active="isActive" @hide="hide" :position="position">
                <slot name="menu">

                </slot>
            </v-dialog>
        </div>
    </template>
```

child-of-child component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="dialog-container">
            <div class="dialog-header">

            </div>
            <div class="dialog-body">
                <slot>
                      //here the ul and lis are basically displayed
                </slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your problem but if you want a global emitter handler a common pattern is to create a singleton of a vue instance and import it when you need it.

`src/bus/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const bus = new Vue()

export default bus
```

`src/components/Whatever.vue`

```
import bus from 'src/bus'

// And then in your functions
bus.$on(...)
bus.$emit(...)
bus.$off(...)
```

If you're looking for a more structured event system, you should take a look at the store pattern with [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).